# Phonegap App, Html/Css Android old Browser debugging

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, cross-browser

I make an app via Phonegap which is working fine. But only on Android 4.4, of course it is because of the new browser engine which is rendering the page since 4.4.

But now i want to make the App suitable for lower versions. And the only solution i've found so far is build the applikation and then run in an emulator. Cause i use "Phonegap build" it takes like 5-10min to check if my change in the Css sheet works. 
I hope there is a better way to do it.

Is there any emulator for old android browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create all the AVDs (Android Virtual Devices) you want, with the android version and hardware you want. But AVDs are slow.

You can use [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) too, genymotion creates virtual machines with android images in VirtualBox. They are fast and almost as reliable as real phones, if you don't want to spend a lot in devices, this is the way to go.

Microsoft has created something like genymotion, if you use windows you can test it on the latest visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

From the Cordova project [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/)

Set up

```
sudo npm install -g weinre

weinre --boundHost -all- <!--for all other than localhost-->

<script src="http://<your ip address>:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script> <!--include on all pages to be tested-->
```